# HQL - COALESCE or CASE on LEFT JOIN

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have 4 tables:

| job |
| --- |
| client |

| order |
| --- |
| client |

| client |
| --- |
| state |

| state |
| --- |
| name |

I need to get a client's state name from a **job** OR **order**. If job is **not** null get from job, else get from order.

I tried something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN job.client jc
LEFT JOIN order.client oc
LEFT JOIN COALESCE(jc.state, oc.state) clientState
```

but I get an *unexpected token: COALESCE* exception.

I also tried:

```
LEFT JOIN job.client jc
LEFT JOIN order.client oc
LEFT JOIN CASE WHEN job IS NOT NULL THEN jc.state ELSE oc.state END clientState
```

but I get an *unexpected token: CASE* exception.

Any idea on how to solve this? Should I try multiple JOINS with state table (jc.state and oc.state) and use the CASE in the projection? Isn't there an easier way?

Thanks in advance

Extra info:

This query could be solved like the example below. My main question is if there is a better way of doing this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN jcClientState IS NOT NULL THEN jcClientState.code ELSE ocClientState.code END 
FROM job job
LEFT JOIN anotherTable anotherTable
LEFT JOIN job.client jc
LEFT JOIN anotherTable.order oc
LEFT JOIN jc.state jcClientState 
LEFT JOIN oc.state ocClientState
```

Comment: Hello, the query you are trying to do is not very clear to me. Is your WHERE for a specific order/job or for a client or do you want to list all orders and jobs with the status of the client?

Comment: I need all client's state name. No WHERE clause over here. In my model, sometimes the job will be null, so I get the client from the order.
I'm adding some extra info to the post.

Comment: If you believe that the question still confusing, I'll delete this post. Maybe I'm not being able to elaborate que question very well

Comment: select coalesce(table1.state, table2.state) from table 1 left join table 2.

Comment: @Isolated. That's what I thought. There's no way of adding that to the JOIN right?! 
Please elaborate more your answer to not be considered just a comment and I'll accept it.

Comment: Maybe could you show the relationships of those 4 tables? For me that query would make sense if the model was something like: Order -> OrderClient (attributes: order, client, status) <- Client and Job -> JobClient (attributes: job, client, status) <- Client. In other words, the client is partitioned for Order and for Job. But I can't quite understand your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming HQL supports coalesce (appears as such when doing a quick search), then you can use coalesce like this:

```
    select coalesce(table1.state, table2.state, 'unknown') as state
    from table1
    left join table 2
      on table2.id = table1.id
```

The coalesce will grab the first non-null value.